# Punctuation Problem-o

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks

If you end a question with a proper noun that requires quotation marks, i.e. a play's name, do you still put the question mark (?) inside the quotation marks?

EXAMPLE: Did you see "South Pacific"? -or- Did you see "South Pacific?"

Answer (score 1):

The question mark goes outside of the quotation marks, because the question mark is not part of the title.

But, if the question mark *was* part of the title, you would write:
Did you see "What About Bob?"?

See: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/how-to-use-quotation-marks

Comment: Your first statement is correct; your second, not so much. Your source doesn't give an example of doubled question marks, and I'm not sure why anyone would pay attention to Grammar Girl. It's not that she's wrong; it's that she's not much of an authority. The *Chicago Manual of Style* notes that multiple punctuation is "limited to instances involving quotation marks, parentheses, brackets, or dashes." *CMS* doesn't give an example of doubled question marks either, but I infer from their instructions that the second would be dropped. Other style manuals may differ.